# Very basic Hello World Wordpress Plugin

Tags: wordpress

What I'm looking to do is create a very basic plugin for Wordpress. I've followed countless tutorials and examples, but haven't found anything close to what I'm looking for.

I'm trying to create something simple where it has a link on the admin nav bar, and just shows some static html on the right side of the page. The public wouldn't see anything at all.

This sounds like a simple task, but so far, has been everything but simple. Any help or pointing in the right direction would be appreciated. :)

Comment: This is StackOverflow please share some code of what you yourself tried so far. Code is King here. :3

Comment: What have you tried yourself to do this? Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Stack Overflow is not a coding service. You are expected to research your issue and make a good attempt to write the code yourself before posting. If you get stuck on something *specific*, come back and include a clear outline of the exact issue, a summary of what you tried and the relevant code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Create a folder named helloworld in your plugins folder and add a file called helloworld.php. In your PHP file, use a hook to add the link to the admin menu.

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Hello World
*/

add_action('admin_bar_menu', 'add_navbar_item', 100);

function add_navbar_item($admin_bar){
  $admin_bar->add_menu( array(
    'id'    => 'my-item',
    'title' => 'My Item',
    'href'  => '#',
    'meta'  => array(
      'title' => __('My Item'),            
    ),
  ));
}
```

Comment: @shane-t Take a look at my example.